# Why is Java.lang.Process not throwing InterruptedException in this code?

Tags: java, process, timeout, processbuilder, interrupted-exception

This method uses ProcessBuilder to run an external C program through my Java application.
I have set it to wait for 1000 ms.
I'm passing it a code that goes into infinite loop.
But the process never throws interruptedException.

```
    public void execute(String sourceFileName, long timeout,String inputFile,String outputFile,String errorFile) 
            throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        ProcessBuilder builder=new ProcessBuilder(sourceFileName+executableFileExtension);
        Process process=builder.start();
        process.waitFor(timeout,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
```

I also noticed that the method returns the control but the process keeps running in the background.
Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**method returns the control but the process keeps running in the background** - because you have specified a timeout limit and by that time, your C program has not finished. You yourself saying that its an infinite loop.

**I'm passing it a code that goes into infinite loop. But the process never throws interruptedException.**

> waitFor()

documentation says that

> Throws:
>       InterruptedException - if the current thread is interrupted by another thread while it is waiting, then the wait is ended and an
>   InterruptedException is thrown.

Your current thread is not interrupted by any other Thread so it doesn't throw InterruptedException.

Your program's behavior doesn't seem erroneous.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Documentation of Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-):

> Returns:
>   true if the subprocess has exited and **false if the waiting time elapsed before the subprocess has exited**

So intead of listening for `InterruptedException`, you should check return value of `waitFor()`.